# How can I protect images embedded in swf files?

Tags: flash, obfuscation

I need to protect images embedded in a swf file.

I've noticed [Swf Encrypt](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/) scrambles the images, like so:

[image: scrambled/coloured noise image]

How is something like this achieved ? **How does image scrambling work** ?
I've noticed the image is stored a bitmap. Not sure how information is stored.

I imagine it would be possible to use something like [AS3SWF](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/) to access the
content of a swf, but what would I need to change for the image swf tags ?

I don't know much about security/obfuscation/encryption, so any tips will be handy. 
The programming language for this shouldn't matter much.

Comment: what do you mean by what you need to change for the image swf tags? are you talking about specific settings inside swf encrypt, the flash ide, or as3swf?

Comment: @matt what I was thinking is, maybe I could import images in the Flash IDE as usual, but once the a swf is compiled, I could change the bytecode to scramble the image, so when someone attempts to decompile to swf to get to the resource images, they will be scrambled

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but it might be tricky - you'd basically have to decompile the .swf to the point where you could tell which bits refered to the image, and disable or corrupt them - but when the .swf was served to a viewer, those scrambled bits would have to be fixed - and once the viewer was served the 'fixed' file, you'd be stuck with the same problem of them being able to decompile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the image scrambling works similar to how plain text looks 'scrambled' once it's encrypted - if you apply the right cipher to the seemingly randomly coloured pixels in that example image, each pixel becomes the correct colour, revealing the image.

That cipher or key to unscrambled it must be somewhere accessible to the .swf, so that whenever the .swf loads that image, it pulls it apart pixel-by-pixel, checks that against the key, and then rebuilds the image.

Comment: thanks for the tip. unfortunately I don't know anything about security/ciphers/etc. Any hints where I should go for a nice and easy start ?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with them myself. :}   What specifically are you trying to do - are you trying to set up an encrypted image in a .swf you're building, or are you trying to decompile a .swf that you think uses encrypted images?

Comment: yes, when/after building the swf to hide the content of asset images inside a swf from decompilers.